# How to all the details of record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find, response

I have a post request which saves the data in the following format

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1bb15a8f7748197b175b9f"), 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-11-27T06:31:54.288+0000"), 
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-11-27T06:32:22.943+0000"), 
    "sensorData" : {
        "isLinked" : true, 
        "assetsLinked" : [
            {
                "ref" : ObjectId("5a1bb1638f7748197b175ba2"), 
                "type" : "obdDevice"
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "rfIdTag", 
                "ref" : ObjectId("5a1bb1708f7748197b175ba8")
            }, 
            {
                "ref" : ObjectId("5a1bb1768f7748197b175bad"), 
                "type" : "driver"
            }
        ], 
        "carNo" : "car123", 
        "assetName" : "car123", 
        "make" : "Toyota", 
        "modelNo" : "Camry", 
        "dutyType" : "Public Taxi", 
        "sensorType" : "car", 
        "sensorLabel" : "Taxi"
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

ref is the id of other document in the same collection

trying to write a query where on single find request all the data must be returned from the db

I mean it should return all the data of the reference id also

tried to unwind and a find but not sure please help to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$sensorData.assetsLinked"},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collectionName",
      localField: "sensorData.assetsLinked.ref",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "assetsLinked"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "updated_at": {$first: "$updated_at"},
      "sensorIsLinked": {$first: "$sensorData.isLinked"},
      "sensorCarNo": {$first: "$sensorData.carNo"},
      // select as you need
      "assetsLinked": {$push: {ref: {$arrayElemAt: ["$assetsLinked", 0]}, value: "sensorData.assetsLinked.value"}}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "updated_at": "$updated_at",
      "sensorData.isLinked": "$sensorIsLinked",
      "sensorData.carNo": "$sensorCarNo",
      // project as you need
      "sensorData.assetsLinked": "$assetsLinked"
    }
  }
])
```